# 'Include' operation EntityFramework WPF App

Tags: c#, database, wpf, entity-framework-core

I want to make a selection of a "Friend" table including the phone number which is in another table "FriendPhoneNumber" linked to the Friend table via Id

Friend Class

```cs
public class Friend
{
    public Friend()
    {
        PhoneNumbers = new Collection<FriendPhoneNumber>();
    }
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int? FavoriteLanguageId { get; set; }
    public ProgrammingLanguage FavoriteLanguage{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<FriendPhoneNumber>PhoneNumbers;
}
```

Class FriendPhoneNumber

```cs
public class FriendPhoneNumber
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Phone]
    public string Numeber { get; set; }

    public int FriendId { get; set; }
    public Friend Friend { get; set; }
}
```

Méthode Select

```cs
public async Task<Friend> GetByIdAsync(int friendId)
{
    return await context.Friends
        .Include(f=> f.PhoneNumbers)
        .SingleAsync(f => f.Id == friendId);
}
```

FriendDatabase Table
[FriendDatabase Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdd0O.png)

PhoneNumberDatabase Table
[PhoneNumberDatabase Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckh0L.png)

When I call the LoadAsyncFriend method
i have this exception, someone have an idea to solve this problem

[image: Error]

Comment: try to declare the collection with getter and setter like : 
public ICollection<FriendPhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }

Comment: I didn't pay attention, it worked thank you

Comment: Next time, please don't post images but text.